# Did Emperor Nero burn Frankincense equal to Oman's annual production at his wife's funeral?

Tags: history, ancient-rome

In a documentary about  Oman  -[**The Paradoxical Life In Muscat  -  Magnificent Megacities**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMUnAwbJVX0&feature=youtu.be&t=2701)     it is narrated that -

> According to the legend, Emperor Nero burned the whole of Oman's annual production at his wife's funeral.

As stated on this site ( Introduction  section )-  The [**annual production of Omani frankincense**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4928835/#:%7E:text=The%20annual%20production%20of%20Omani,rural%20household%27s%20income%20%5B4%5D.) ranges between 80 to 100 tons from nearly 500,000 trees.

But it's not pretty clear that he burned the frankincense equal to the annual production of Oman during his or current time. Same is about [**which**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wives_of_Nero) wife.

Is there any historical or modern evidence that shows that this claim is true or is it just a legend as said in the documentary.

Comment: The wife referenced by the documentary is almost definitely [Poppaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppaea_Sabina).  One wife was banished by Nero and one survived beyond Nero.

Comment: More a question for [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes , the question is suitable  for both the sites.